# Get another timezone info, locally, using VBScript

Tags: datetime, vbscript, timezone

I have a little challenge I'd like your help with.

I have a central server, in CET/CEST (Western Europe) timezone.

I'd like to know, at any time, the time difference between this server and other computers, in BRT/BRST (Brazil) timezone and KST (Korea) timezone.

The firewall settings prevent me from querying the computers directly, or a time server.

I think all the information is available locally, since when I use Windows 'Additional Clocks' feature, I can get the time in any timezone, accounting for DST both here and there.

The challenge is how to do it in VBScript.

I have seen that I can read registry keys at

```
    \\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones
```

but it does not seem to account for DST.

As anyone ever tried to do something like this, and is willing to share his/her findings?

Thank you for your help

Maxime

Comment: Could you leverage  `.NET` Framework [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime Method (DateTime, TimeZoneInfo, TimeZoneInfo)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770(v=vs.110).aspx)  in Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JosefZ suggested, using PowerShell was a very good idea;

```
Dim PSCommand
Set Shell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")

PSCommand = "powershell -command [String]$zone = 'Korea Standard Time';[TimeZoneInfo]$tz = [TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById($zone);[TimeZoneInfo]$local_tz = [TimeZoneInfo]::Local;[DateTimeOffset]$now = [DateTimeOffset]::UtcNow;[TimeSpan]$zone_offset = $tz.GetUtcOffset($now);[TimeSpan]$local_offset = $local_tz.GetUtcOffset($now);$diff = $zone_offset - $local_offset;$mydiff = $diff.Hours;Write-Host $mydiff"

Set Executor = Shell.Exec(PSCommand)
executor.StdIn.Close
wscript.echo executor.StdOut.ReadAll()
```